# Is Git Shell Windows Power Shell?

Tags: windows-7, shell, git, powershell

I have a simple question. What is Git Shell? IS it the same as Windows Power Shell?

Because when I run Git Shell on my Windows 7 machine the Windows Power Shell is opened.

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you install [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), you can assign the shell dynamically:

[image: Go to Tools, then options...]

[image: Select your preferred shell]

Which type is picked by default is decided during setup.

Comment: Btw. has PowerShell more benefits than using just Git Bash? I am new in this area, so thanks for any advice.

Comment: @Derfder: If you like to use PowerShell cmdlets, use the PowerShell. If you're more familiar with bash, use the Git Bash. In regards to git itself, I never noticed a difference.

Comment: So, what do you use personally on a daily basis, if I may ask?

Comment: @Derfder: I use the PowerShell host. I like bash better in general, but working with bash on Windows just feels weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using msysgit then the git shell is actually a msys shell that utilizes [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and provides a bash shell implementation for windows.

Because msys leverages MinGW it also provides reimplementation of some of the standard GNU programs written for windows that are useful when operating git.

Comment: I have an icon on my desktop called "Git Shell" (that comes with Git for windwos installer) . And when I double click it Windows Power Shell starts. Why?

Comment: There's a number of possible reasons, maybe the shortcut is broken or sh.exe is aliased to Windows PowerShell. Either way Git Shell is a separate entity to PowerShell

Comment: Where is sh.exe located, so I can start it?

Comment: Typically the areas where you command line programs come from (like sh.exe) can be found in the PATH variable. If you do echo %PATH% in a regular shell that will show you all the possible folders it could be in.

Comment: echo %PATH% in Git bash returns %PATH%.

Comment: In bash it would be $PATH

Answer (score 0):

n PowerShell, create a folder called NOS130LASTNAME (Your last name) in the C: Drive. Create another folder within the NOS130LASTNAME folder called Scripts.  Use the command(s) to show the 2 folders you created.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).